# web3.min.js undescriptible bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web3js, react-scripts

i'm working on a react project and when I run it with npm run start from react-scripts it works but when i use npm run build and test it on a local express server, i got this :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
    i web3.min.js:25038
    l web3.min.js:25037
    i web3.min.js:25036
    exports web3.min.js:25192
    exports web3.min.js:25193
    r web3.min.js:13
    exports web3.min.js:24116
    r web3.min.js:13
    exports web3.min.js:19276
    r web3.min.js:13
    exports web3.min.js:3847
    r web3.min.js:13
    exports web3.min.js:19238
    r web3.min.js:13
    exports web3.min.js:48
    <anonymous> web3.min.js:49
    f account:1
    423 Bet.jsx:20
    f account:1
    200 walletconnect.png:1
    f account:1
    a account:1
    e account:1
    <anonymous> main.f01fcd85.chunk.js:1
```

I already used npm run build to test in production my project but now i can't find what's wrong...

I tried to remove the react component involved (Bet.jsx), I tried to update web3js and I tried an older version of my project to make sure my backend works

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should provide the  command launched by "npm run build" in your package.json